# How Do I detect window of X corresponding to Y (nonlinearly)?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, independence, association-measure

I have two continuous variables that may have nonlinear relationship.
The dataset contains multiple recordings of X, each corresponding to multiple recordings of Y.
The exact matching is unknown.

How Do I detect window of X corresponding to each Y?
Should I use distance correlation tests with sliding window of X?

UPDATE:
X are EEG recordings.
Y are sound recordings.
Each EEG recording corresponds to multiple sound recordings.
I want to process EEG and corresponding sound in parallel.

Comment: This terse, abstract description makes it difficult to understand your problem.  Could you perhaps supply a small example of the data and what you intend to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you have observations $(x_i, y_i)_i$ from the joint distribution $p_{X,Y}$. It seems you are asking about the quantity
$$\mathrm{Supp}(p_{X\mid y}) = \{ x\mid p_{X\mid Y}(x\!\mid\!y) > 0 \}$$

You should be able to estimate the joint pdf $p_{X,Y}$ of your data. This can be done via a good ol' [KDE estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) or via the [use of copulas](https://twiecki.io/blog/2018/05/03/copulas/). Both methods have implementations in R and python.

This however goes against [Vapnik's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transduction_(machine_learning)), so there must be a simpler way to estimate the support of $X\mid Y=y$ without the estimation of the entire pdf.

If your goal is to estimate a conditional distribution on complex domains such as soundwaves or images, consider using [conditional generative models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf).

Comment: That does not answer the question: How Do I detect window of EEG corresponding to each sound recording?